# LINQ Joining multiple tables using row index/number

Tags: c#, linq

I have an excel template for uploading records to database and it has multiple sheets.
I am able to join the sheets' data on upload using LINQ and this is my code:

```
var query = from component in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            join componenthazardous in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
            on component.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            equals componenthazardous.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            join manufacturers in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
            on component.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            equals manufacturers.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            join vendorinfo in ds.Tables[3].AsEnumerable()
            on component.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            equals vendorinfo.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            join crossreference in ds.Tables[4].AsEnumerable()
            on component.Field<string>("PartNumber")
            equals crossreference.Field<string>("PartNumber")

            select new { 
                PartNumber = component["PartNumber"].ToString(),
                Description = component["Description"].ToString(),
                Hazardous = componenthazardous["Hazardous"].ToString(),
                M_MfgrCode = manufacturers["MfgrCode"].ToString(),
                M_MfgrName = manufacturers["MfgrName"].ToString(),
                M_Status = manufacturers["Status"].ToString(),
                M_AsOf = manufacturers["AsOf"].ToString(),
                M_Remarks = manufacturers["Remarks"].ToString()
            };
```

Now, my problem is that my boss suddenly changed the requirements. On excel template, the key I used to join the tables are duplicated. Its uniqueness will be based on the combination of PartNumber and MfgrName. How can I join the tables using this combination as key if only one sheet has these rowcolumns?

My idea is that I'll use row number as my key for joining since the partnumber column on other sheets is referenced from the first sheet/datatable but I don't know how. Any idea or any other way to solve this?

Thanks.